# How to hide zero values from an excel 3d surface graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I am currently trying to put together a 3D surface graph in Excel 2013. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

The area on the left is the proper chart - displaying actual data I have. The area on the right is excel interpreting empty cells that are not in the domain of my graph as 0 and graphing them as if the value was there.

I tried making sure the value in the cell is empty by using this function:

```
=IF(($C6>(0.02/(1-D$5))), $C6*(1-D$5)/(-0.02+$C6*(1-D$5)), "")
```

But again, excel things "" is the same as 0 and graphs it.

How can I make Excel not try to graph values that are not there and moreover - vertical surfaces between the existing and nonexisting values?

Comment: Try using NA() instead of blank.  That forces the entry to be treated as not available.

Comment: @fixer1234 Tried that, same result.

Comment: Does the graph change if you actually remove those entries and consolidate the data?  I'm not sure I'm seeing the values you're referring to and wondering if what you're seeing might be part of how Excel renders the graph rather than "data".

Comment: @fixer1234 Tried removing everything from the empty cells, still displays as zeroes. I can't really remove the p and m domain that produces that data since they are also used elsewhere in the chart.

Comment: Excel doesn't plot anything (just a gap in the chart), for NA().  Looking at your image, the only "zero" values I'm seeing on the right is a uniform "floor", which I think Excel includes as the way it renders the graph in order to make it easier to visualize the 3D space.  Without that, it would be hard to distinguish what the graph is showing.  My suggestion was to consolidate the data (or a copy of it), so there are no empty rows in what gets graphed.  If you get the same result, you will know that what you're seeing isn't "data".  You also might be able to change the floor color.

Comment: In a 3D surface graph, it doesn't seem to give you the option to show hidden and empty cells as gaps. [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TPegp.png)

Comment: It's not the floor because I can format the [floor as red](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wYIEN.png) and it shows up. I think the behavior stems from the fact that 3D surface charts create bins and so it's filling in zero values for all your empty data. You can change the bin size by [decreasing the vertical axis unit size](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AvxOG.png) but that looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a similar problem by changing the Axis Options to:

- Bounds: Minimum .5
- Units: Minor 1
- Floor Crosses at: Axis Value 0.0
- Number > Catagory > Number > Decimal Places = 0

This way the Axis starts showing for a number >=1, and the floor appears blank for any value below that – in my case to not display 0 values in a 3D graph.

Comment: Good idea! However, it dindn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution (and there is one...sortoff)

You can select an individual 'colour band' and change its transparency setting to 100%. That way the band disappears from the figure. See example result. It is still there, but just like white letters in a word document, invisible.

It does pose some limitations obviously. You need to make sure that all 'empty' cells fall into a band range without any other values in it.

So in your case:

- Change the empty cells to a negative vale of -1
- create a new band going from [0 - (-1)]
- select band settings, and set transparency to 100%
- select band legend entry (if applicable) and change letter colour to white

I am sure that for you it is too late already, but since I could not find this solution anywhere else I might just as well post it here for the next poor soul encountering this limitation.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJnMp.png)